# Search for a string within a multiple PDF`s metadata with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, metadata

How can I search multiple PDF files in directory for a specific 'Author' name and get a path to that file if found? Currently I'm browsing through directory using `EnumerateFiles` and then I'm looping through to display all the Author names from each PDF file with `PDfReader`. I just don`t know how to search now for that specific Author name.

My code below:

```
path = @"C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\PDFfiles";
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string currentFile in files)
{                 
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(currentFile);
    string authorName = reader.Info["Author"];

    listBox1.Items.Add("Author is: " + authorName);
}
```

I'm getting a list of Authors names in my `ListBox`, but how I can search for a specific name within all PDF files?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use new list to save results with your selected author such as: `newList = listBox1.Items.Where(x => x.Text == authorName);`

Comment: I agree. The answer is as simple as this. I wonder why someone would ask a question with such a trivial answer, but you deserve an up-vote for this after the down-vote I gave you for a previous answer that was wrong. You can undo a down-vote by removing the wrong answer (actually, it would be better to remove that answer, because it is misleading for people who might mistake it for a correct answer).

Comment: Hi, I`m aware of the fact that I can save the search results to the list, an 'array' etc. but, how to avoid this. The reason I`m asking is that this will search in the folder with possibly 100.000 pdf files. Any idea ?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for saying that, I will delete my answer in another thread.

Comment: @Thomas If you have to search through all the files in a folder, you have to search through all the files in a folder. What else do you expect??? Tell the person who has put 10K files in a folder that it was stupid of him not to create a database to store metadata and a link to the files with the corresponding metadata. Now you have to create that database after the fact.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.